# SQL Error: 595 - Bulk Insert with another outstanding result set should be run with XACT_ABORT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server ***2008 R2 SP3*** (10.50.4000.0)
When trying to do bulk insert through C#,

I see in trace there is always an error:

> Error: 595, Severity: 16, State: 1

I read the support page about this error

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2412203

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5be1bab7-74c1-4d1c-a6f7-7d0c925dce12/bulk-insert-with-another-outstanding-result-set-should-be-run-with-xactabort-on?forum=sqlintegrationservice](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5be1bab7-74c1-4d1c-a6f7-7d0c925dce12/bulk-insert-with-another-outstanding-result-set-should-be-run-with-xactabort-on?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

SQLServer, in this case, is already updated with SP3.

Not sure what is causing the Error 595. Could you please provide some inputs on this.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

C# code snippet.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(m_Connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, m_Transaction) { DestinationTableName = TableName })
        {
            foreach (DataColumn columnName in StagingTable.Columns)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(columnName.ColumnName, columnName.ColumnName));
            }

            bulkCopy.BatchSize = BULK_COPY_BATCH_SIZE;

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(StagingTable);

            bulkCopy.Close();
        }
```

Comment: So you then proceeded to make sure `XACT_ABORT` is set to ON, right?

Comment: XACT_ABORT is set ON

Comment: Can you add the stored procedure in question to your question? Or perhaps create a repro-procedure?

Comment: @TT. Here We are using SqlBulkCopy from C# code.

Comment: Ok. But in your question you are stating the following: *When trying to do bulk insert through stored procedure*. It's hard to tell more about the problem without seeing at least some more details, i.e. the exact code you are using to do the bulk insert.

Comment: @TT. Apologies, I have updated the question with code snippet.

Comment: How did you conclude that the `XACT_ABORT` setting is in fact ON in the session you are doing the bulk insert from? PS: you are closing an object that is created in a `using` clause... IIRC that object will be disposed of automatically for you (been since 2007 that I've coded in .NET, but I think I still remember that much).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131812/discussion-between-tt-and-satech).